# PHP fails to set cookie with a specific database result, but works with all the others

Tags: php, cookies

I'm using PHP (with PDO) to retrieve a list of rows from the database and setting a cookie to be used throughout the session. The following code works for every case *except* one particulary large list (actually I don't think that an array of 30 items is that large, but...). When I try to retrieve the list for that specific input, the cookie creation fails.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/connection.php");

if($user->loggedIn() !== true) {
  $user->redirect('login.php');
}

if(isset($_POST["usrSendList"])) {

  $list = trim($_POST["usrList"]);

  $getLists = $permissions->getLists($list);
  setcookie('getLists', serialize($getLists));
  header("location: ./somewhere-else.php");
}
?>

  <form method="post">
    <select name="usrList" id="usrList">
      <option value="" selected>Select a Company</option>
      <?php
      $listCompanies = $permissions->listCompanies();
      foreach ($listCompanies as $company_name) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $company_name["company_name"] ?>"><?php echo $company_name["company_name"] ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="usrSendList" id="usrSendList" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
```

I've tested the database output inside the Permissions class and can confirm that it's working as intended (returning an array of "list" strings), but here's the code anyway:

```
<?php
class Permissions{

  private $db;

  function __construct($conn) {
    $this->db = $conn;

  }

  public function listCompanies() {
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT company_name FROM table_permissions GROUP BY company_name;");
    $query->execute();
    $listCompanies = $query->fetchAll();
    return $listCompanies;
  }

  public function getLists($list) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT permession_id, permission_contract FROM table_permissions WHERE company_name = :list GROUP BY permission_id, permission_contract;");
    $query->bindparam(":list", $list);
    $query->execute();
    $getLists = $query->fetchAll();
    return $getLists;
  }

}

?>
```

So, since the database output is working, I guess it has something to do with the cookie, but I couldn't really figure it out. the output of `print_r($_COOKIE['getLists'])` is nothing, meaning that the cookie is not even being created. There's nothing on the error log also.

Comment: The size of `cookies` should not be more than **4093 bytes**

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui oh, that explains it, I don't know the exact size of the output, will measure and come back to confirm if that's the problem

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui nope, serializing the result array and using *strlen* on the resulting string returns 3244 bytes. It must be something else